# Is it possible to launch an iPhone debugserver without jailbreaking using lldb or xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, gdb, lldb

I was wondering if it's possible to create a completely custom debugger for the iPhone. To do this I would need to read the process of my app installed in the iPhone. While I think this is not possible, there may be a workaround through lldb.

From Xcode, when you launch your app you can see a PID (process id) that the Xcode debugger attaches to. This PID is not available on macOS, it's local to the iPhone and cannot be inspected directly in any way.

I discovered that the iPhone uses a **debugserver**, which is a way of doing remote debugging from macOS with Xcode.

The way it works, is that when you launch your app from Xcode, a service called **debugserver** is launched inside the iPhone that starts *LISTENING* for TCP packets at some port that I guess Xcode specifies and then from macOS you send TCP packets to the iPhone, using the gdb-remote protocol. This practice is nothing special and you can read more about it here: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/remote.html

I inspected TCP connection using the following command:

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP
```

Then sniffing the packets using this command: (where the IPv6 belongs to the iPhone)

```
sudo tcpdump -i en0 -p -vv -A ip6 and net de90:4::31:e77b:81f1:5cdb
```

Every time I create a breakpoint or step through in Xcode I see packets traveling with tcpdump.

The issue is, that Xcode establishes the connection, and the port is no longer in *LISTENING* mode, but rather *ESTABLISHED*. So I can't simply send packets.

What I need to do is to execute debugserver that is located in the iPhone, the command should look something like this:

```
lldb-server platform --listen "*:1234" --server
```

Anyway I can do this? Because Xcode can, I don't see why I couldn't do the same from the command line terminal. I need to either do it completely using lldb or running an Xcode command that puts the connection in listening mode and stops before establishing it, so I can establish it myself through lldb.

It seems to be possible using jailbreak (source:https://iphonedev.wiki/index.php/Debugserver)

Using this command:

```
./debugserver *:1234 -a "YouTube"
```

Resulting in this:

```
My-iPhone-5S:~ root# ./debugserver *:1234 -a "YouTube"
debugserver-300.2 for arm64.
Attaching to process YouTube...
Spawning general listening thread.
Spawning kqueue listening thread.
Listening to port 1234 for a connection from *...
```

I'm looking to do exactly that without jailbreaking as I'll only debug my own apps and because Xcode can do it I assume I can too.

Comment: Did you manage to find something on that topic? I came up with the same conclusions as you, but I don't see any tool that could start the debugserver. I browsed all tools from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`. There is `xcdebug` but it just launches the app using Xcode

Comment: I discovered that on my device, before starting debugger there is a running process `/System/Developer/usr/libexec/dtdebugproxyd`. Probably this is responsible for starting `debugserver`. Maybe Xcode connects via TCP/IP with it and instructs it to start the `debugserver`.